# Autofill cells with condition

Tags: excel, cells, autofill, vba

I'm stuck with a code. I admit I´m not an expert programmer, but despite already having spent a good bit of time searching in the internet, I am not able to build the code. The situation is this.

I've got in SheetB 2 columns (A and C). In column A I have a bunch of ID numbers and there are always more rows with the same number (ex: ID 12345 is in Row 6 to 15). To each ID number there is a corresponding date in column C.

In SheetA, in Cell C4 I select the ID number and I want to create code that automatically fills the column F (sheetA) starting from row 12 with all the available dates matching the ID in SheetB.

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use this code within your Sheet1 code... feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Edit: Slightly changed clean-up routine.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim oCell As Excel.Range
Dim oCellResult As Excel.Range
Dim oCellClean As Excel.Range
Dim oRangeID As Excel.Range
Dim iCellCount As Integer

If Target.Address = "$C$4" Then

    'Set source data
    Set oRangeID = Sheets(2).Range("A:A")

    'Define initial target for the results obtained
    Set oCellResult = Sheets(1).Range("F12")

    'Clear up any previous data
    'Set oCellClean = oCellResult
    'While Len(oCellClean.Value) > 0
    '    
    '    oCellClean.Clear
    '    Set oCellClean = oCellClean.Offset(1, 0)
    '    
    'Wend

    Set oCellClean = Range(oCellResult, oCellResult.End(xlDown))
    oCellClean.ClearContents

    'Scans source range for match data
    For Each oCell In oRangeID

        If oCell.Value = "" Then Exit For

        If oCell.Value = Target.Value Then

            oCellResult.Offset(iCellCount, 0).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            iCellCount = iCellCount + 1

        End If

    Next oCell

End If
```

End Sub

**Edit:**

Updated clean up code. Check if it fits your expectations.

Comment: It seems i have an error "1004". The Debug showes this oRangeResult.Clear. I´ll try to fix this

Comment: Hi, I've changed the cleanup routine. I believe we won't have error 1004 anymore. Besides, added some comments to ease code's understanding.

Comment: Hello. The code looks good but it´s not doing it. The values in the destination sheet don´t apear. It´s odd.

Comment: Add a breakpoint into the codeline _oCellResult.Offset(iCellCount, 0).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value_ and check if, when the code halts in the break point, the value is in the right side of the statement (i.e. in Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value). To see the value of this code, just move the cursor over this code.

Comment: I´m sorry i was doing something wrong. Your new code doesn´t work. The values simply don´t appear. I apreciate your effort though.

Comment: It may not work in your environment @user676827, but as per your problem description, I simulated the environment in my Excel (2007) and it worked fine. Where the problem lies? What is the code line failing? What's the error description?

Comment: The value simply don´t appear. Can it be by renaming sheets(2) for worksheets("Reg") ?

Comment: @user676827 yes, it might work as well. You can discover if Sheets(2) is pointing to the correct sheet simply running the code `? sheets(2).name` in the immediate window. Alternatively, you can put a 'msgbox sheets(2).name within your code, if you're not used to use immediate window.
On the other way round, you can discover the index of "Reg" sheet by running the code `sheets("Sheet2").index`. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: No :( . I simply do not understand...the excel file is with macro permission..i just don´t know where to look. You said that you have simulated the code. It is possible for you to send me the file please? I just don´t know where i´m screwing up

Comment: Have you changed the worksheets(2) to Worksheets("reg") and it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. I´ve changed the worksheets, changed range("...") to cells (  , )...nothing seems to work

Comment: It´s working! I was messing with sheets. Thank you! Just one question (if i´m not pushing my luck). Let´s supose instead values in Collum C, i would want to auto fill with value in collum C (dates) and collum D (address). I added CellResult1, CellResult2 but it´s not working. Can you help me? THe code is in the next comment

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

`Dim oCell As Excel.Range`
`Dim oCellResult1 As Excel.Range`
`Dim oCellResult2 As Excel.Range`
`Dim oCellClean As Excel.Range`
`Dim oRangeID As Excel.Range`
`Dim iCellCount As Integer`

......

    `Set oCellResult1 = Sheets("Folha1").Range("F12")`
    `Set oCellResult1 = Sheets("Folha1").Range("E12")`
......
 `oCellResult1.Offset(iCellCount, 0).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value`
`oCellResult2.Offset(iCellCount, 0).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 3).Value`
 `iCellCount = iCellCount + 1`

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso
Forget it, i already managed. Thanks for your help and patiente!

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso

I have a minor issue. The code is not cleaning the previous data because there is a row with no value (blank space). It´s possible to fix this?

Comment: Hi @user676827, is this scenario expected? Theoretically it shouldn't happen, unless there's an empty cell in the source data.

Comment: Yes there is an empty cell in the source data. I know that one collum of the source data is always fill so i changed to `While Len(oCellClean1.Value) > 0` ignoring the oCellClean2. It seems to do the trick but now i´m facing another problem. When the cell cleanup is made, the cell borders within the range are "reset" (the cells borders are fill with a thin black line).

Comment: Thank you. I really apreciate your help. Thank you so much

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . Hello. Something new as come up, i only have this to finish the excel macro file. It the code you you have written, is there a way to continuing to fill up in other row? For example, lets says that if can only fill up from Cell U14 to  Cell U25. If the Target.Adresses values have more than 12 values. i want the fill up to resume let´s says from Cell U40. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you could keep populating the values as we're doing now but adding a test in iCellCount. When iCellCount > 11, then you increment iCellCount value in let's say 20 values.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . How do i increment? i have wrote iCellCount = (iCellCount + 11) + 1 but the values aren´t followed, they are spaced by 11 rows

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . I´ve tried with While..when function and i´m not getting it. If you could help that would be great. I apreciate your patience

Comment: Ah, you need to increment only ONCE, not always. You'll add a test to check if the iCellCount is 11 and then do the increment.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . how do i do that test? I´ve search it on google and excel help but i haven´t found it

Comment: You'll add something like if iCellCount = 11 then iCellCount = iCellCount + 20.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso .  Thanks!!! It worked! Just a simple thing...i have spend all morning in this...i really apreciate. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Welcome, mate! Glad to know it worked! For next questions, I believe you'll need to start a new post, as these comments are getting harder to read :)

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . You are right. I just have one final question and then it´s over. I´ve tried with a third increment but it seems is not working. I´ve tested the first for `if iCellCount = 11 then iCellCount = iCellCount + 20` and then in the next line wrote `if iCellCount = 19 then iCellCount = iCellCount + 40` but this isn´t working in the way that the line isn´t being read by the macro.

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . Forget it! I´ve nailed it! Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso . It is possible to filter the autofill (data values) between two dates? For example Just to show the dates between 01-01-2008 and 31-12-2009? I opened another question regarding this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586055/filter-results-by-date-or-by-beetwen-two-dates). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim rgIDsAndDates As Range: Set rgIDsAndDates = Range("name")
Dim DATEs As Collection ' to collect date values for a given ID
Dim IDs   As Collection ' to collect all the DATEs collections for all IDs

' step 1: loop to create (initially empty) collections for each unique ID
Set IDs = New Collection
Dim rgRow As Range
For Each rgRow In rgIDsAndDates.Rows
    Set DATEs = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    ' the foll line will save an (empty) DATEs collection keyed by the ID
    Call IDs.Add(DATEs, CStr(rgRow.Cells(1, 1).Value))  ' col 1 as the ID
    On Error GoTo 0
Next rgRow

' step 2: loop to fill each DATEs collection with the dates for that ID
For Each rgRow In rgIDsAndDates.Rows
    ' the foll line retrieves the DATEs for the corresp ID
    Set DATEs = IDs(CStr(rgRow.Cells(1, 1).Value)) ' col 1 has the ID
    Call DATEs.Add(rgRow.Cells(1, 3).Value)        ' store the date from col 3
Next rgRow

' for testing ... list the dates for ID "123"
Set DATEs = IDs("123")
Dim dt As Variant
For Each dt In DATEs
    Debug.Print "date: " & dt
    ' put that dt where you want
Next dt
```